# How can I cash in my stock certificate from Cable & Wireless Jamaica?

Tags: stocks, foreign-exchange, share-certificate, jamaica

I have a ordinary stock certificate from Cable & Wireless Jamaica from 1999 that my grandmother left me which says it’s for 6,053 units, units = dollars. I have the certificate receipt from bank as well. Can I cash it in, and if there’s a possibility of doing so, how? Thank you in advance for any helpful advice and or information!

Comment: I assume that's Jamaican dollars. JSE has the stock in April trading at 1.4 so it might not be worth trying to cash it.

Comment: The units on a certificate would typically indicate how many shares were purchased, not the value of those shares.

Comment: @HartCO Presumably that's the nominal value, which is less than a US cent. Sadly, they aren't worth that much more.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=5503834

"JSE Approves Cable & Wireless Jamaica Delisting
Apr 9 18
The Jamaica Stock Exchange (JSE) has approved a request by Cable & Wireless Jamaica (CWJ) to delist its stock on 11 April. Flow Jamaica – offered to purchase some three billion stock units back on 28 December 2017, at a price of JMD 1.45 (USD 0.01) per unit."

Looks like you need to contact them and get your buyout. Also looks like you're going to have to do some digging to find out specifically who to contact, as CWJ seems to have been bought out by Cable & Wireless (West Indies) Ltd. which operates as a subsidiary of CWI Group Limited.

There is an address and phone number here: https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapid=22676318

Comment: note that 1.45 JMD x 6053 = 69.29 US $ as of today.